# How to skip an optional question in Through The Loop?

Tags: bug, status-completed, survey

"This is an optional question. Select one of the options." - but there's no "don't want to answer" or "skip," only a set of radio selects. Once you do select an answer, an "ok" button appears - but what if you don't wish to answer? Is the optional question actually mandatory, or how do I skip it?

> [image]

Comment: When something like this happens in a survey, I usually enter `-` (or more, if there's a min length)

Comment: Did that where "Other" was an option. How do you do that on a radio select? (See image)

Comment: I think you can just scroll down.

Comment: Mystery meat navigation? "If you already know how to do it, that's how you do it." Appropriate to the survey...

Comment: Don't think this is SO's fault... The same issue occurs when people try to take my school's survey.

Comment: @JL2210 : Yeah, looks so. With the recent SE breakdowns, I was predisposed to assume bad intent.

Comment: Everybody is now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just scroll down to the next question.

Comment: Thank you. Not sure how that's supposed to be discoverable, but it answers the question.

Comment: @Piskvorcc-by-sa3.0 I came upon it when I just scrolled down to look at the next question.

Comment: Interesting. Didn't occur to me that moving up/down is possible.

Comment: @Piskvorcc-by-sa3.0 Yeah, its the fault of the design of the website, where they sticky-lock the scroll and gray out anything above/below. I hate it.